# Access private GitHub Django repositories on requirements.txt when using AWS Codebuild

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, github, aws-codebuild

I am trying to use AWS Codebuild and am having problems accessing private python Django github repositories from my requirements.txt file.

Getting this error "Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Is there a solution to enable access?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/private-python-packages.html

You need to create a personal access token with the repo scope. Check the GitHub documentation on how to create a personal token.

URI example:

```
git+https://${GITHUB_USER}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/user/project.git@{version}
```